# Task API - How to refactor asynchronous call to synchronous call yet able to capture desired Exception (ApiException)

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

Currently, I have the following asynchronous call, using Task API.

### Asynchronous

```
Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = googleSignInClient.silentSignIn();
if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
    task.addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
        // Now, this is main thread.
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = task1.getResult(ApiException.class);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            if (e.getStatusCode() == GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) {
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I would like to refactor it to synchronous call.

### Synchronous

```
Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = googleSignInClient.silentSignIn();

try {
    // How to capture ApiException in Tasks.await
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = Tasks.await(task);
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I was wondering, how can I capture the desired `ApiException`, like what I did using `task.getResult(ApiException.class)`?

Answer (score 2):

Just came around this: looking at the source of `Tasks.await()` it wraps `ApiException` (or any `Exception` thrown by the task) in an `ExecutionException`:

```
private static <TResult> TResult zzb(Task<TResult> task) throws ExecutionException {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        return task.getResult();
    } else if (task.isCanceled()) {
        throw new CancellationException("Task is already canceled");
    } else {
        throw new ExecutionException(task.getException());
    }
}
```

So get the cause and check if it is an `ApiException`:

```
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    if (cause instanceof ApiException) {
            String statusCodeString = GoogleSignInStatusCodes
                    .getStatusCodeString(((ApiException) cause).getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Tested with `play-services-tasks` version `16.0.1`.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks